# How to use join with MixedId field and another field as ObjectId in Mongoose

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mean

I am using join for 2 schemas which are as below :-

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var CompanySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    address: String,
    address2: String,
    url: String,
    geoLat: String,
    geoLon: String,
    telephone: String,
    npi:String,
    active: Boolean,
    tax_id:String,
    businessTypeId:[
        {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'BusinessType'}
    ],
    partners:[{type :Schema.Types.Mixed, ref:'TradingPartners'}]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Company', CompanySchema);
```

Schema 2 :-

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TradingPartnersSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
id: String,
enrollment_required: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
supported_transactions: Schema.Types.Mixed,
is_enabled: Boolean,
clearinghouse:String,
last_updated:String

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('TradingPartners', TradingPartnersSchema);
```

Now I am using below code for join which is throwing an error, in my controller :-

```
exports.findCompanyById = function(req, res) {

    Company.findById(req.params.id)
      .populate('partners')
      .exec(function (err, company) {
        console.log(company);
        if(err) return res.send(500, err);
        return res.send(204);
      });
};
```

I am getting below error after running service. Can anyone please help?

```
{"message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[object Object]\" at path \"_id\"","name":"CastError","type":"ObjectId","value":{"id":"56dfa20249c25b7a3290596e"},"path":"_id"}
```

Comment: Per [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), only `ObjectId`, `Number`, `String`, and `Buffer` are valid for use as `refs`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your req.params.id
is an object console log req.params.id and find id from that object

or

partners:[{type :Schema.Types.Mixed, ref:'TradingPartners'}] change to

partners:[{type :Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'TradingPartners'}]